# PowerShell regular expression 14 digits

Tags: regex, powershell-3.0

I have a regular expression I'm trying to get working to match the `LastLogon` property in the `Win32_NetworkLoginProfile` object. So far I have the following:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkLoginProfile |
    Sort -Descending LastLogon |
    Select * -First 1 |
    where { $_.LastLogon -match "(\d{14})" }
```

However, this doesn't seem to match the 14 digit output of the attribute in the object. I think it could be a error with the regular expression I'm using but I cant for the life of me work it out.

Comment: Is your statement actually wrapped like that (`* -First 1` being on the next line)? It worked just fine when I put everything in a single line.

Comment: its on a single line, what output do you get when you run the command? For me it spits out all the attributes, I was after only the LastLogon attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just one attribute you need to select just that attribute (or expand it if you want just the value), otherwise PowerShell will display the default display property set of the object. To extract the date and time portion before the decimal point simply remove the decimal point and everything after it.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkLoginProfile |
    Sort -Descending LastLogon |
    Select-Object -Expand LastLogon -First 1 |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\..*' }
```

Comment: Thanks for this however the output is still 0171124110043.000000+000 so the regular expression doesnt seem to be only catching the first 14 digits